# Running an ASP.NET application on Linux using mono and mono-fastcgi-server4 in combination with NGINX

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, mono, fastcgi

I am trying to run an ASP.NET application in a Linux Docker container. For that I use a mono image (mono:5.12) and install a mono-fastci-server4 on it. Another container runs an NGINX proxy, mapping subdirectories to containers. This works well for proxy_pass which I use for my Jenkins and Git containers, but it doesn't work for fastcgi_pass, at least not for more than one subdirectory.

To be more exact:
As long as I run the assignment container behind one subdirectory, everything works perfectly fine, but when I put it behind two subdirectories everything breaks. I feel really lost and would appreciate any help!

First my working configuration:

NGINX.config (generated in my docker container)

```
upstream assignment {
    server 10.0.0.8:9000;
}
upstream course-git {
    server 10.0.0.4:8080;
}
upstream course-jenkins {
    server 10.0.0.10:8080;
}

# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;

resolver 127.0.0.11;

server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;

    location /assignment {
        root /;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass assignment;
    }
    location /course/git {
        proxy_pass http://course-git/course/git;
        # HTTP 1.1 support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
        # Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
    location /course/jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://course-jenkins/course/jenkins;
        # HTTP 1.1 support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
        # Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
}
```

Start Script of mono-fastcgi-server4

```
echo "#!/bin/sh\nexport MONO_OPTIONS="--debug"\nfastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/assignment:/course/assignment /socket=tcp:\$(ip -4 addr show \$BIND_TO| grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'):9000 /verbose=True /printlog=True" > /opt/mono-fastcgi
```

Now the broken one:

NGINX.config (generated in my docker container)

```
upstream course-assignment {
    server 10.0.0.14:9000;
}

upstream course-git {
    server 10.0.0.10:8080;
}
upstream course-jenkins {
    server 10.0.0.4:8080;
}

# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;

resolver 127.0.0.11;

server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;

    location /course/assignment {
        root /;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          "";
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass course-assignment;
    }
    location /course/git {
        proxy_pass http://course-git/course/git;
        # HTTP 1.1 support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
        # Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
    location /course/jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://course-jenkins/course/jenkins;
        # HTTP 1.1 support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
        # Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
}
```

Start Script of mono-fastcgi-server4

```
echo "#!/bin/sh\nexport MONO_OPTIONS="--debug"\nfastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/course/assignment:/course/assignment /socket=tcp:\$(ip -4 addr show \$BIND_TO| grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'):9000 /verbose=True /printlog=True" > /opt/mono-fastcgi
```

The error I get when trying to access the assignment container through my NGINX proxy is the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Failed to map path '/course/_ViewStart.cshtml'

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath (System.String virtualPath, System.String baseVirtualDir, System.Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) [0x0011a] in <eae422b9b12f4162853d52b85a26cb6e>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath (System.String virtualPath) [0x00012] in <eae422b9b12f4162853d52b85a26cb6e>:0 
  at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath (System.String virtualPath) [0x00033] in <eae422b9b12f4162853d52b85a26cb6e>:0 
  at System.Web.Hosting.DefaultVirtualPathProvider.FileExists (System.String virtualPath) [0x00013] in <eae422b9b12f4162853d52b85a26cb6e>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache.<.ctor>b__4 (System.String path) [0x0000b] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x00034] in <b0e1ad7573a24fd5a9f2af9595e677e7>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache.FileExists (System.String virtualPath) [0x0000e] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.ExistsInVpp (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.Exists (System.String virtualPath) [0x00010] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.Exists (System.String virtualPath) [0x00016] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase page, System.Web.WebPages.IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, System.String appDomainAppVirtualPath, System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] supportedExtensions) [0x00036] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage (System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase page, System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] supportedExtensions) [0x00063] in <801d2c34932044b184a3f58959254712>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer, System.Object instance) [0x000b3] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render (System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext viewContext, System.IO.TextWriter writer) [0x00067] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context) [0x00080] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000b] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Int32 filterIndex, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext preContext, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0009b] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] filters, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult) [0x0000a] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21+<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c () [0x0008a] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00041] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState innerState) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.Controller+ExecuteCoreState].invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState(System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Controller/ExecuteCoreState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5 (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState innerState) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1[System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler+ProcessRequestState].invoke_void_IAsyncResult_TState(System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler/ProcessRequestState)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncVoid`1[TState].CallEndDelegate (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <02dcf88f5d2c40b9b769e815214e0dd7>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.async_handler_complete_cb (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00015] in <eae422b9b12f4162853d52b85a26cb6e>:0
```

Is it even possible to run a mono-fastcgi-server4 behind multiple subdirectories? I didn't find any example using more than one subdirectory. If not, any other suggestions, how I could solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!